# IIS Redirect With Parameters

Tags: iis, redirect

Good day,

I have a URL as such:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/2017/12/28/article-name/News/19391`

Assuming

**`$1`** = `/2017/12/28/article-name`

And **`$2`** = `/19391`

How can I set up a redirect rule to redirect

`http://www.mywebsite.com/$1/News/$2`

to `http://mywebsite.com/redirects/?path=$1&id=$2`?

I'm not IIS fluent at all, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this steps:

1. Create redirect which will match your URL. In your case, regexp can be `^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.*)/News/(\d+)$`
2. Create the URL which you want to receive as redirect `/redirects/?path=/{R:1}&amp;id=/{R:2}` where {R:1} is `2017/12/28/article-name` and {R:2} is `19391`
3. Combine it in one rule

At the end, your rule should be like that and you should place it in your web.config:

```
<rule name="news redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.*)/News/(\d+)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/redirects/?path=/{R:1}&amp;id=/{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give that a shot. I appreciate your help!